# Angular data binding not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I have been struggling with data binding in ASP.NET webforms, using AngularJs.

I have the following angular:

```
 (function () {
        var app = angular.module("registrationModule", []);

        app.factory("exampleService", exampleService);

        function exampleService($http) {
            function getData(id) {
                return $http.post("LegacyPage.aspx/GetData", { id: id })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data; //data comes back as json
                   //Also tried response.data.d
                });
            };

            return {
                getData: getData
            };
        };

        app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "exampleService", MainCtrl]);

        function MainCtrl($scope, exampleService) {

            $scope.generateText = "Generate";
            $scope.loading = false;


            function onComplete(data) {
                Unload(data);
            }

            function err(reason) {
                Unload("Ajax has failed.");
            }

            $scope.GetData = function (id) {
                Load();
                exampleService.getData(id).then(onComplete, err);
            }

            function Unload(result) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.generating = false;
                $scope.generateText = "Generate";
                $scope.theData = result; //does not work

                //I have tried (with no success):

                //$scope.$apply(function () {
                //$scope.theData = result;
                //});

                //$scope.theData = JSON.parse(result);

                //$scope.theData = angular.fromJson(result);
            }

            function Load() {
                $scope.loading = true;
                $scope.generating = true;
                $scope.generateText = "Generating...";
            }
        };

    }());
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="registrationModule">

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" ng-model="id" />
        <input ng-click="GetData(id)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="{{generateText}}" ng-disabled="generating" />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span10">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Activity Code</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Date Created</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="element in theData">
                        <td>{{element.ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{element.ActivityCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{element.Duration}}</td>
                        <td>{{element.DateCreated}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind/Backend c#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(int id)
{
    var dt = GetData(id);

    if (dt == null) return "";

    var json = dt.Serialize() ?? "";

    return json;
}

public static string Serialize(this DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("dt parameter cannot be null");
    }

    try
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        Dictionary<string, object> row;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Essentially, the data is coming back as JSON but is not being successfully bound. I am getting the JSON back in angular, but I am not able to handle it. I think I am just missing something very simple, but have yet to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured it out. The issue was the ng-repeat not being able to bind the data. That's because the data was coming back as a string. So each property of each object was a string, angular apparently doesn't like that. All I needed to do was change the back end code to this:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<ReportData> GetData(int id)
{
    var dt = GetData(id);

    if (dt == null) return dt;

    var reportElements = dt.ToObjectList<ReportData>();

    //var json = dt.Serialize() ?? "";

    return reportElements;
}

public class ReportData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ActivityCode { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
{
    try
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            T obj = new T();

            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So now it is returning a generic list of a class I created. I map my datatable to the class using an extension method. In my service I now use:

```
     function exampleService($http) {
        function getData(id) {
            return $http.post("LegacyPage.aspx/GetData", { id: id })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data; //data comes back as json
               //Also tried response.data.d
            });
        };

        return {
            getData: getData
        };
    };
```

and in my unload function:

```
 $scope.theData = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found your problem. In your getData() function, you named the id argument "studentId", but were referring to it as just "id" later on. Here's the fix:

```
function getData(studentId) {
    return $http.post("LegacyPage.aspx/GetData", {
        id: studentId // This used to be "id", but needed to be "studentId"
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

**EDIT**

Sounds like your issue might be that your API is returning a single hash object like so:

```
$scope.theData = {
    ID: 1,
    ActivityCode: 'foo'
    ...etc
}
```

If that's the case, you don't need to use the ng-repeat directive to show one object. You would simply change your view like so:

```
<div ng-app="registrationModule">

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" ng-model="id" />
        <input ng-click="GetData(id)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="{{generateText}}" ng-disabled="generating" />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span10">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Activity Code</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Date Created</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{theData.ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{theData.ActivityCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{theData.Duration}}</td>
                        <td>{{theData.DateCreated}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would only need to use the ng-repeat directive if your API is returning an array of objects to iterate over like so:

```
$scope.theData = [{
    ID: 1,
    ActivityCode: 'foo'
    ...etc
}, {
    ID: 2,
    ActivityCode: 'bar'
    ...etc
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is just an example, it is actually id in my real code. The issue now is with the ng-repeat

Comment: @user3574076 No worries. After setting the response on the scope, can you confirm that $scope.theData is an array? Try doing a console.log($scope.theData) right after setting it.

Comment: see my answer, I figured it out

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding the `response.data` to any variable. You need to add a `$scope.theData = response.data;` in your controller.

**[Edit:]** Correction, got confused by your code. Change your controller from:

`$scope.theData = result;` to `$scope.theData = result.data;`

As for your service, get rid of the `.then(...)` because it doesn't do anything.

```
        function getData(studentId) {
            return $http.post("LegacyPage.aspx/GetData", { id: id });
        };
```

Unless you meant to alter the response, in which case you need to add a `return`:

```
        function getData(studentId) {
            return $http.post("LegacyPage.aspx/GetData", { id: id })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        };
```

As for standards, I suggest using `.catch(err)`, because then you can chain several `.then(...)` statements and still use a single error handler. It's also easier to read.

```
exampleService.getData(id).then(onComplete).catch(err);
```

Comment: yes sorry for confusion, I was also missing a return statement. I have edited the `exampleService` in my question. Also tried `.data.d`

Comment: @user3574076 Still not working...? It should at this point. Try shimming the `["$http", exampleService]` in your service.

Comment: @user3574076 If that still doesn't work, use `console.log(response);` in the `.then(...)` part of your service to see what is output in Google Chrome > Console (F12). If that looks fine, do `console.log(result)` in your Unload statement to see what is being output there. Test your chain like this to see where it's breaking.

Comment: @ngDeveloper testing it now, will let you know the outcome

Comment: @user3574076 In `$scope.GetData = function (id) { ... }`, try also `console.log('id:', id);` to see if the id is even being injected as expected. You can just as well use `$scope.id` here intead of using the function argument.

Comment: @ngDeveloper, data is present in service and in unload, so `response.data` contains `d`, which contains: "`[{"ID":280417,"ActivityCode":"MA5111","Duration":20,"DateCreated":"\/Date(1433469835860)\/"},{"ID":280417,"ActivityCode":"MA5112","Duration":7,"DateCreated":"\/Date(1433469835903)\/"}...`

Comment: @ngDeveloper also changed it to how you suggested but did not work, still nothing binding

Comment: @user3574076 Looks like you need to do `$scope.theData = result.d;`. I don't know where the `*.d` is coming from, looks like something your back-end is adding.

Comment: @user3574076 Try `return response.data.d;` in your service, and then `$scope.theData = result;` in your controller. But right before the line in your controller, add `console.log("Data:", result);`. Then in your template, right above the table, add on a separate line `{{theData}}`. See what that outputs.

Comment: @ngDeveloper will try that now

Comment: @ngDeveloper ok so it logged the same stuff as before, and right before the table all the data bound fine. Looked just like my earlier comment. However, none of it is getting bound in the ng repeat

Comment: @ngDeveloper so it appears that it cannot access each element. For example ID is actually "ID" - So I am now trying to find a way to fix that

Comment: @user3574076 Maybe the backend server is returning invalid json, or it's not setting the header mime-type as application/json, so Angular treats it like a string. You can try something like `console.log(JSON.parse(result));` in your controller `Unload()`. Note that JSON.parse(...) is only for modern browsers.